# Android grave accent isn't shown on canvas, when hardware accelerate is true

Tags: android-canvas, diacritics, hardware-acceleration, text-rendering

everyone. 
This is my first question in stackoverflow.
I hope you understand my poor English.

I found strange issue on drawing grave accent on canvas. I have been testing that drawing text on canvas on android, then I realize that hardware accelerated canvas doesn't draw few grave accents.

Here is codes and properties.

- hardwareAccelerated : true

  ```
  canvas.drawText("\u0E36", 100,  100, paint);
  canvas.drawText("isHardwareAccelerated : " + isHardwareAccelerated(), 150, 200, paint);
  ```

  above codes doesn't draw \u0E36 character on canvas.
- hardwareAccelerated : false, Unicode with space(or any string)

  ```
  canvas.drawText(" \u0E36", 100,  100, paint);
  canvas.drawText("isHardwareAccelerated : " + isHardwareAccelerated(), 150, 200, paint);
  ```

  above codes draw \u0E36 character on canvas.
- hardwareAccelerated : false

  ```
  canvas.drawText("\u0E36", 100,  100, paint);
  canvas.drawText("isHardwareAccelerated : " + isHardwareAccelerated(), 150, 200, paint);
  ```

  above codes draw \u0E36 character on canvas.

I realized that when I set hardware acceleration true, grave accents doesn't shown without string.

but, if I put any characters or space just before the grave accent, it works.

and, if I set hardware acceleration false, canvas draws grave accents without any string.

**My question is that why canvas doesn't draw grave accents when canvas is hardware accelerated?**

I could guess it is related with hardware rendering and software rendering.
But I don't know exactly why.

here is what I want to draw on canvas with hardware acceleration.
It's Thai character. and I found some latin grave accents also doesn't shown on canvas.

http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x0E36/index.html

My reputation points is 0, so I can't post pictures of them.
I hope you guys understand my poor English.

Comment: Google has already explained that: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html  See the list of unsupported drawing operations